# Http POST method goes to test.com sometimes instead of localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, post

I am experiencing a very strange behavior. I am doing a simple ASP .NET application that will upload a file to the server.
I have a simple form that does this:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-group">
                <label for="files" class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 control-label">Bestand *</label>
                <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8" ">
                    <input name="file" type="file" id="file" required />
                <span >@ViewBag.TheMessage</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-md-push-3 col-sm-push-4">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Versturen" />
                </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

The strange thing happens with the POST, 9 of 10 times this POST goes to test.com instead of localhost. I sniffed it with firebug to discover this. The firebug looks like this:
[image]

The Controller.cs looks like this, and it's working fine when post reached:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        ViewBag.TheMessage = "Thanks, an e-mail will be sent shortly";

        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Another strange thing is that if I just use an empty format cshtml file only with:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<input type="submit"/>
```

POST woks fine every time.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe some base path

Comment: form class="form-horizontal" method="post" - This in cshtml will trigger a POST when the submit button is pressed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to see if you have any Javascript that is changing your forms action attribute. I would start by looking at onload, onsubmit, or on your submit buttons onclick method. If you're using jquery be sure to check your `$(document).ready ()` function. This really could be anywhere in your js though so make sure you look everywhere.

Another culprit could be that you have a base tag in your html that looks something like `<base href="http:www.test.com />` which will change all of your relative urls to go that base location

Comment: I erased all javascripts attached to the cshtml and it worked...i didn;t discovered what exactly it was, but it worked 5 times in a row

Comment: There is a nice little tool called Visual Event. I use it with chrome but there is a FireFox version available too. It will show you all of the events on any page. As a web developer I find it to be an invaluable tool and it's free